# Should I remove Firebase observer even if it's single event?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Firebase documentation on observers for Swift are either a bit outdated or aren't too clear for me. I still don't really understand WHEN exactly to remove observers. What about in the case of observeSingleEvent? Also, where is a proper way to remove these observers?

Comment: There are a couple of good answers already but the 'WHEN' and 'Should I remove' part of the  question is situational. If you are talking about the mechanics, that's outlined in the docs and the answers. I think the real answer would be revealed when you post some code and a Firebase structure and describe what you are doing. Then we can answer the WHEN part.

Answer (score 2):

[Firebase's documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write) does not specify this, but it seems implicit, so I wouldn't remove it:

> #### Read data once
>
> In some cases you may want a callback to be called once and then immediately removed, such as when initializing a UI element that you don't expect to change. You can use the observeSingleEventOfType method to simplify this scenario: the event callback added triggers once and then does not trigger again.

To remove an observer, attach it to a handle before, then use that handle as a reference:

```
// Add observer
let handle = ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { value in
    // ...
})

// Then remove it
ref.removeObserver(withHandle: handle);

// Or just remove all of them
ref.removeAllObservers()
```

Comment: Mostly correct, but it depends a bit on the type of event you listen for. You are observing a `.value` event, in which case the listener will invoke right away with either the current value or null (if there is no current value). So in this case, the listener is removed right away. But if you observe a child event, that event may not fire straight away, for example when you observe `.childAdded` on an empty list. In that case the listener will stay on the reference and may need to be removed, for example when leaving the view controller.

Comment: Correct, single observers stop observing after the first occurrence. I just assumed OP knew this. My fault :)

Comment: @Alan Tell me, if I do so removeObserver (withHandle: handle), then only a specific observer is deleted, right? I just want to clarify one detail for myself.

Comment: @Alexander Yes, just that one is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of reading data once:

```
let firebase = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

// Access The Posts child of the database
self.firebase.child("Posts").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in

 if let snapVal = snapshot.value {
     // Iterate through posts..
    // Note that if you want to iterate though a snapVal, the best way to to so would be through converting it to a Dictionary of [String: AnyObject]!
}

})
```

**To answer your specific question:**
Removing the observer should not be an issue because the observer is **only observing once**, you would essentially just be confirming that the observer is gone.